# sed command to insert a character before another character with a 'not' match

Tags: regex, sed

File is like :

```
#comment1 
 some executable code
#comment2
 some executable code
```

I want to insert two hashes before 2nd and 4th line, so I tried,
sed 's/^[^#]/##/g'  but that replaces the first character ('s' in 2nd line), like :

```
#comment1
##ome executable code
#comment2
##ome executable code
```

But I want to get the output like :

```
#comment1
##some executable code
#comment2
##some executable code
```

Please suggest some way to do this.

Comment: `sed 's/^[^#]/##&/'` ?

Comment: Use `sed 's/^[^#]/##&/'`.  The `&` in the replacement means 'what was matched'.  There's no need for a `g` when the search is anchored at the start of the line; it can only match once on a given line.

Comment: Yes, That worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed 's/^[^#]/##&/'`.

The `&` in the replacement part means 'what was matched'.

There's no need for a `g` when the search is anchored at the start of the line; it can only match once on a given line.  OTOH, it doesn't actually do any damage.

---

I note that for the input file:

```
#comment1 
 some executable code
#comment2
 some executable code
```

your original output would have been:

```
#comment1 
##some executable code
#comment2
##some executable code
```

because the leading space would have been lost.  With the revised script, the output would preserve the leading space:

```
#comment1 
## some executable code
#comment2
## some executable code
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `[^#]` is matching a character you need to place it back in replacement:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*\([^#]\)/##\1/' file
#comment1
##some executable code
#comment2
##some executable code
```

`^[[:blank:]]*` matches 0 or spaces/tabs at start.